# Proving that SO(3) is not isomorphic to another group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-isomorphism

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R} \newcommand\gl{\mathrm{Gl}} \newcommand\sl{\mathrm{SL}} \newcommand\so{\mathrm{SO}}$How do you prove that $\gl(2,\R)/\R^*$ is not isomorphic (as abstract groups) to $\so(3,\R)$?
Initially I thought that because $\gl(2,\R)/\R^*$ is isomorphic to $\sl(2,\R)/\{-I,I\}$ then it is easier to look at $\sl(2,\R)$ but I am not sure anymore. Anything remarkable to know about centralizers and normalizers that could help me here? Actually I am no event sure anymore if they are not isomorphic.

Comment: To see that they are not isomorphic as *topological groups* you can show that one is compact and the other one is not. However, this itself does not exclude the possibility that there is a group isomorphism that is not a homeomorphism, so you're probably looking for a further argument.

Comment: I'm still glad there is a topological argument showing they are not homeomorphic as topological groups. Any argument in the category of groups is also welcome of course.

Comment: You should specify if you are looking for an isomorphism of abstract groups or of Lie groups. The group $SO(3)$ is simple (as an abstract group), while $PGL(2,R)$ is not. (Why?) Another argument will tell apart $SO(3)$ from the (abstractly) simple group $PSL(2,R)$: Consider finite subgroups that they contain. Could you spot the difference?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Thanks! Apologies for not clarifying (I just made an edit that did so). Could you write this same answer in a new answer post so I could mark it as answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The group $SO(3)$ is simple as an abstract group, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453510/so3-has-no-normal-non-trivial-subgroups-except-for-itself-i-e-so3-is-simple). On the other hand, $PGL(2, {\mathbb R})$ contains $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$ as (an/the) index 2 subgroup, hence, is not simple.
2. Another argument is to consider finite subgroups. The group $SO(3)$ contains the simple subgroup $A_5$ as the group of orientation-preserving symmetries of regular dedecahedron. On the other hand, each finite subgroup of $PGL(2, {\mathbb R})$ is conjugate into its maximal  compact subgroup $O(2)$ and, hence, is either dihedral or cyclic. This argument also tells apart $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$ from $SO(3)$.
3. Yet another, harder, argument is to consider infinite solvable  subgroups: $PGL(2, {\mathbb R})$ contains the class 2 solvable subgroup of affine transformations of the real line. In contrast, one can show that every solvable subgroup of $SO(3)$ contains an abelian subgroup of index at most 2.